# IE 10 RSS Feed Reader does not render in a frame. Works fine in its own window

Tags: .net, asp-classic, rss, frame, internet-explorer-10

Ok, I'm maintaining a deployed web application and I have a problem with RSS Feed Rendering using the built-in Reader in IE10.  The RSS feed is rendered within a frame.

The operation of the application works as such.  A link to a page that generates the RSS XML is presented within the frame.  Clicking on that link results in the XML being presented to the browser.

In all browsers except for IE10 using their built-in feed readers this works.
In IE10, a small square near the top-left of the frame is presented instead.
If the link address is copied and then navigated to in its own tab, it renders fine.
If the feed reader is turned off in IE10, the proper XML is displayed.

It just won't work in IE10 in a frame.  I have not found anything yet on Google that covers IE10.  I've tried the disabling zoom from the registry and can verify that this does not resolve any problems.

Does anyone have any other advice to try?  Things I cannot do include forcing users to compatibility mode, forcing users to download an external rss reader, forcing the RSS feed to its own tab.

Thanks,

Matt